# inserting global variable's value from the controller into my mongodb using sails

Tags: mongodb, sails.js

I have created a global variable in my controller like this.

```
var adspace = 0;
module.exports = {
calc1: function (req, res, next) {
        var var1=40;
        User.findOne(req.param('id'), function foundUser (err, user) {
            adspace += var1;
        });
    }
}
```

now, how can I insert my `adspace` value into my MongoDB? 
Thanks.

Comment: Did you check `.create` and `.update` methods? Are you facing some problem with them? http://sailsjs.com/documentation/reference/waterline-orm/models

Comment: Which adapter are you using ? (Connection) sails-mongo or sails-hook-orm-mongoose?

Comment: i m using sails-mongo

Comment: MY CREATE FN  create: function (req, res, next) {
  User.create( req.params.all(), function userCreated (err, user) {

   
   if(err) {
    
    req.session.flash = {
     err: err
    }

    return res.redirect('/user/new');
   }

  // req.session.authenticated = true;
  // req.session.User = user;

   
   res.redirect('/user/show/'+user.id);
   
  });
 },             IT WORKS FINE

Comment: MY UPDATE FN:    updateUser: function (req, res, next) {

     User.update({ name: 'Aarthi' }, { adspace: adspace })
   .exec(function(err, users) {
     
   if(err) return next(err);
  
   console.log(adspace);
 
   res.redirect('/user/show/' + req.param('id'));
  
   adspace = 0;
  }); 
    }